# Webclient's DownloadStringCompleted event handler never called

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I'm trying to make an asynchronous HTTP GET request using Webclient, however, the registered callback never gets called. I've also tried with the sync one, and it worked fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
WebClient asyncWebRequest;
public AsyncWebRequest(Uri url)
{
    asyncWebRequest = new WebClient();
    url = new Uri("http://www.google.com/");
    // string test = asyncWebRequest.DownloadString(url);  // this works
    asyncWebRequest.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(asyncWebRequest_DownloadStringCompleted);
    asyncWebRequest.DownloadStringAsync(url);
}

void asyncWebRequest_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are testing this in a console app and exiting `Main` before your download is finished?

Comment: Eh. Thanks, this was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you disposing the `WebClient` before it finished downloading. The code execution don't stop on `asyncWebRequest.DownloadStringAsync(url);` and you are disposing the `WebClient` object by closing the using statement.

try to dispose the `WebClient` on `asyncWebRequest_DownloadStringCompleted`.

**results**

[image]

Comment: I've updated the code in the question. It's still not working.

Comment: Well, yes, the problem was that I've tested it as a console app, and it exited before this got called. (see the first comment on my question).

Comment: Yes, I saw it. Put `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your `Main` method to wait till the end of async call

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution is to add `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of `AsyncWebRequest(url)` method. This way `asyncWebRequest.DownloadStringAsync(url)` will be able to retrieve data.